# I want to add annotation_logticks() to my ggplot function but they does not appear

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have x-axis in log scale and also have the annotation_logticks in this x-axis. X-axis is not in log scale + annotation_logticks does not appear. Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
r_blade_mp_boottime_10sec <-c(0.987665, 0.999774, 0.999978, 0.999957, 0.998258, 0.996295, 0.987665)
p_blade_mp_boottime_10sec <- c(1557.5, 1189.67, 1476.84, 1348.86, 1510.38, 1530.94, 1557.5)

r_blade_mp_boottime_30sec <-c(0.987749, 0.999736, 0.999934, 0.999947, 0.998213 ,0.996093 , 0.987749)
p_blade_mp_boottime_30sec <- c(1557.33, 1189.86, 1477.06, 1348.82, 1510.1, 1530.7, 1557.33)

r_blade_mp_boottime_2min <-c(0.98768, 0.999623, 0.99977, 0.999871, 0.99802, 0.995959, 0.98768)
p_blade_mp_boottime_2min <- c(1555.99, 1190.74, 1476.15, 1349.49, 1508.96, 1529.78, 1555.99)



rp_blade_mp_boottime_10sec <- data.frame(r_blade_mp_boottime_10sec, p_blade_mp_boottime_10sec)
rp_blade_mp_boottime_30sec <- data.frame(r_blade_mp_boottime_30sec, p_blade_mp_boottime_30sec)
rp_blade_mp_boottime_2min <- data.frame(r_blade_mp_boottime_2min, p_blade_mp_boottime_2min)


blade_mp_boottime <- ggplot() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) + 
  geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(data=rp_blade_mp_boottime_10sec, aes(x=r_blade_mp_boottime_10sec, y=p_blade_mp_boottime_10sec, color = "#2778d8"), size = 3) + 
  geom_point(data=rp_blade_mp_boottime_30sec, aes(x=r_blade_mp_boottime_30sec, y=p_blade_mp_boottime_30sec, color = "#2fdac6"), size = 3) + 
  geom_point(data=rp_blade_mp_boottime_2min, aes(x=r_blade_mp_boottime_2min, y=p_blade_mp_boottime_2min, color = "#bb8fce"), size = 3) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x)) + 
    #breaks = scales::log_breaks(n = 5)
    #breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), + 
  labs(x = bquote("Reliability" ~ (1 - P[f])), 
       y = "Power Consumption (W)", 
       title = "Google Traces", 
       color = "Deployments") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#2778d8", "#2fdac6", "#bb8fce"), 
                     labels = c("10 sec boot time", "30 sec boot time", "2 min boot time")) 

blade_mp_boottime + annotation_logticks(sides = "b")
   
blade_mp_boottime
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried myself with some simulated data and it works for me - what does your data look like and is it possible to post a sample to try with?

Comment: for sure, you can find the data in my question. thanks a lot

Comment: fab - now I'm getting the same problem at least! will see if I can figure something out...

Comment: yeah, it is a little bit weird... i have tried different approaches but i cannot find a final solution

Comment: ah I think it is actually doing the transformation but at the scale of change within your graph it's looking linear. log10 scale would create an equal distance from 0.01 to 0.1 to 1, but the distance from 0.9875 to 0.990 and 0.9975 to 1 here is roughly similar so looks linear. Do you mean to do `1 - r_blade_mpbootime etc.` instead?

Comment: i have made some modification and then i got this plot. it is already x-axis in log-scale? i think so, but i still have the problem with the logticks...

Comment: It's a little beyond my expertise at this point so apologies there, but I think you'd only be expecting logticks to look clearly differentiated in a dataset spanning orders of magnitude - if you try it using 1 minus the value you'll see them show up (even if that's not what you're planning). Graphing things within the range 0.9875-1  I don't think log ticks can work or are useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think Andrew Baxters' suggestion to plot `1 - x` is the best one, if the goal of the log-transform is to reduce the between-group spread of the data. Probably would need a different x-axis title though, but I don't have the domain-specific knowledge to know what the correct one would be. That said, here is how you could do it and what you can expect.

Note that the annotation requires `scaled = TRUE`, since the log-transform scales the data. Also from you code I guessed that you wanted `10^x` notation for the axis labels, so I've added that in too.

```
blade_mp_boottime <- ggplot() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) + 
  geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(data=rp_blade_mp_boottime_10sec, 
             aes(x=1 - r_blade_mp_boottime_10sec, y=p_blade_mp_boottime_10sec, color = "#2778d8"), size = 3) + 
  geom_point(data=rp_blade_mp_boottime_30sec, 
             aes(x=1 - r_blade_mp_boottime_30sec, y=p_blade_mp_boottime_30sec, color = "#2fdac6"), size = 3) + 
  geom_point(data=rp_blade_mp_boottime_2min, 
             aes(x=1 - r_blade_mp_boottime_2min, y=p_blade_mp_boottime_2min, color = "#bb8fce"), size = 3) +
  scale_x_log10(labels = scales::math_format(format = log10)) +
  labs(x = bquote("Reliability??" ~ (P[f])), 
       y = "Power Consumption (W)", 
       title = "Google Traces", 
       color = "Deployments") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#2778d8", "#2fdac6", "#bb8fce"), 
                     labels = c("10 sec boot time", "30 sec boot time", "2 min boot time")) 

blade_mp_boottime + annotation_logticks(sides = "b", scaled = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: thank u so much, your suggestion is really appreciated!